# How to combine multiple arrays in one JSON object

Tags: php, arrays, json, angular, object

I want to display multiple arrays into one such that each time the object is created it get a key value and then forms a object to be more specific following is a short example.

How it is now:

```
name:[{},{},{},{}]
surname:[{},{},{},{}]
phone: [{},{},{},{}]
```

How I want it to be:

```
xyz:[{name:{}, surname{}, phone{}},
     {name:{}, surname{}, phone{}},
     {name:{}, surname{}, phone{}}]
```

I am exporting this in php so that I can use this JSON object in AngularJs ng-repeat directive.

following is the code:

1. declaring array:

   ```
   $name = array();
   $surname= array();
   $phone= array();
   ```
2. assigning values **WHICH IS UNDER FOR EACH LOOP**

   ```
   $name[] = $values ($values wil have the values for the loop)
   .....
   ```
3. testing output

   ```
   <?php echo json_encode($name);
       echo json_encode($surname);
       echo json_encode($phone);
   ?>
   ```

Comment: Just put the array inside of that array:$finalArr = [ $name,$surname ];

Comment: One small advice.I'd rather spend more time making a RESTful API which will handle all the background jobs.And form angular make the calls.Try out Slim it's easy and it will help you out a lot.

Comment: @FirstOne this is a magento site so data is coming via php in For loop

Comment: @Arslan.H Its a magento site working on MVC frame work only way to take the data is through this php variables in a  for loop

Comment: @FirstOne yeah its looks correct let me try once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of doing it ([run](https://3v4l.org/2a7Xq)):

```
$name = array("name 1", "name 2");
$surname = array("surname 1", "surname 2");
$phone = array("phone 1", "phone 2");

$output = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++){
    $output[] = array(
            'name' => $name[$i],
            'surname' => $surname[$i],
            'phone' => $phone[$i],
        );
}

print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => name 1
            [surname] => surname 1
            [phone] => phone 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => name 2
            [surname] => surname 2
            [phone] => phone 2
        )

)
```

Note: It assumes all arrays are of same size and have same keys.

But maybe it would be better to instead of saving each value to 3 different variables and then running this script, try saving the values already into the array as the desired output (if possible, of course, since we can't know).